# What word is John looking for?

Tags: riddle, word

John knew this obscure word but forgot. He went to the word oracle but was bombarded with these riddles instead:

> Earth has one?
>    Half man, half bull?
>    Amongst Mercury's
>   eight neighbours but slower?
>   Child of Red and Green?
>    Slimy, slippery but can shock you?
>   He was raised by apes?
>   It mimics words but can't comprehend them?
>    This is at the
>   core of this and all of us?
>  Woolly Dolly was one?
>   Runs
>   through wires?
>    Shadowfax showed us it's meaning?
>    I am
>   air-borne but at night?
>    Indian has two? 
>   Every problem
>   has one?

Somebody help poor John.

Comment: poor sod won't ever get help with so many clues to match

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the word is

> metempsychosis

(credit to @hexomino , @keelhaul , @rhsquared , and @lee-leon ; some of the below were either directly from your answers/comments, or derived from them)

Earth has one?

> **M**oon (note: there are other possibilities, but this is the only one that fits with the final word)

Half man, half bull?

> **M**inotaur

Amongst Mercury's eight neighbours but slower?

> **S**ilver

Child of Red and Green?

> **Y**ellow (note: you get Brown when you mix these colors IRL, but Yellow when you combine the color codes: (255,0,0) + (0,255,0) = (255,255,0). Yellow is also "in between" green and red at stoplights)

Slimy, slippery but can shock you?

> **E**el

He was raised by apes?

> **T**arzan

It mimics words but can't comprehend them?

> **P**arrot

This is at the core of this and all of us?

> **S**oul (note: metempsychosis means "transmigration of the soul", and the soul is also at the core of us humans)

Woolly Dolly was one?

> **C**lone

Runs through wires?

> **E**lectricity

Shadowfax showed us it's meaning?

> **H**aste

I am air-borne but at night?

> **O**wl

Indian has two?

> **I** (the letter)

Every problem has one?

> **S**olution

Taking the first letters gives you

> MMSYETPSCEHOIS

which unscrambles to the answer.

Comment: Good job, Captain!

Answer (score 12):

An observation:

Amongst Mercury's eight neighbours but slower?

> Mercury, the element, is also known as **Quicksilver**. In the periodic table, Mercury (Hg) is surrounded by 8 other elements, one of which is Silver (Ag). Silver, logically, must be slower than Quicksilver, so the answer is **Silver**

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer:

Earth has one?

> Satellite

Half man, half bull?

> Minotaur

Amongst Mercury's eight neighbours but slower?

> Venus is the slowest planet

Child of Red and Green?

> Brown

Slimy, slippery but can shock you?

> Eel (Electric eel) Thanks @hexomino

He was raised by apes?

> Tarzan

It mimics words but can't comprehend them?

> Parrot

This is at the core of this and all of us?

> 

Woolly Dolly was one?

> Clone

Runs through wires?

> Electricity

Shadowfax showed us it's meaning?

> Haste (again thanks @hexomino) although not sure on the horse's link to haste

I am air-borne but at night?

> Owl

Indian has two?

> n's  (thanks @prit.patel) although some native american's have two braids.

Every problem has one?

> Solution

Comment: Earth has more than one of those, though.

Comment: @RickvanOsta But just one natural.

Comment: I think that rot13(Funqbjsnk fubjf gur zrnavat bs unfgr).

Comment: Also rot13(Fyvzl, fyvccrel ohg pna fubpx lbh? vf cebonoyl 'rry')

Comment: Maybe   Vaqvna unf gjb a'f

Comment: Puvyq bs Erq naq Terra - vfa´g vg oebja vafgrnq bs lryybj?

Comment: @Doomenik You might be correct.

Comment: Also, Irahf vf abg gur fybjrfg cynarg, va snpg gur beovgny fcrrq vaperzragf jvgu gur cebkvzvgl gb gur Fha

Comment: @Keelhaul Now, again, that depends on which speed we are talking about.

Comment: @rhsquared The only speed I find relevant is the orbital one, but you may have another idea, can you tell me which speed you are thinking of ?

Comment: @Keelhaul Rotational speed.

Comment: @rhsquared Indeed, now we shall guess what OP had in mind as "speed" :p

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer** (with some from @rhsquared& @hexomino)

Earth has one?

> Moon

Half man, half bull?

> Minotaur

Amongst Mercury's eight neighbours but slower?

> Pluto (not a planet, but probably the 8th neigbour) has the slowest orbital speed. However, the riddle says slower, and every other planet of our solar system is slower than Mercury.

Child of Red and Green?

> Brown (thanks @Doomenik)

Slimy, slippery but can shock you?

> Eel

He was raised by apes?

> Tarzan

It mimics words but can't comprehend them?

> Parrot (thanks @rhsquared)

This is at the core of this and all of us?

> 

Woolly Dolly was one?

> Clone (thanks @rhsquared)

Runs through wires?

> Electricity

Shadowfax showed us it's meaning?

> Haste (thanks @hexomino)

I am air-borne but at night?

> Owl (thanks @rhsquared)

Indian has two?

> "I" ? Or "N" as @prit.patel noticed

Every problem has one?

> Solution

Now what to do with all this is a mystery...

Comment: Abg "V" orpnhfr bayl "Vaqvn" jbhyq or rabhtu sbe gung. Fb V gubhtu bs "A".

Comment: @Keelhaul Who's @peerless?

Comment: @rhsquared The OP I mistakenly copied the name instead of yours^^ I fixed it

Comment: @Keelhaul You were still right, though, because peerless created the puzzle :)

Comment: For the first answer could be so much right, I like rot13(rnegu pber)

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

Couple of alternative possibilities for some:

Earth has one?

> Probably is Moon or Satellite, but could be **Atmosphere**

Child of Red and Green

> If mixing colours, could be **Yellow**. At a stretch, could also be **Apple** (child is the apple of my eye/apples are red and green)

I am air-borne but at night?

> **Bat** or **Moth**

Indian has two

> Again a stretch, the Indian Ocean has two **arms**

Answer (score 1):

@CaptainPlanet probably has the answer, but just in case that's wrong I wanted to contribute an additional observation:

This is at the core of this and all of us?

> Not counting the question mark, this riddle is 41 characters (31 letters long).
> The middle ("core") letter is **O**. The same is true of "all **o**f us".